# OpenAI GPT-3 API error: "You must provide a model parameter"

Tags: swift, openai-api, gpt-3

I am trying to POST a question to openAI API via SWIFT. It works fine, if I use the same payload via Postman, but in the Xcode-Condole I got the following response from openAI:

```
Response data string:
{
     "error": {
         "message": "you must provide a model parameter",
         "type": "invalid_request_error",
         "param": null,
         "code": null
    }
 }
```

This is my code:

```
 func getActivityAnalysis(){
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions")
    guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
    
    // Prepare URL Request Object
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
    request.setValue("Bearer blaaaablaa", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    
    let prompt = "just a test"
    let requestBody = OpenAIRequest(model: "text-davinci-003", prompt: prompt, max_tokens: 300, temperature: 0.5)
    
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    let data = try! encoder.encode(requestBody)
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
    
     
    // Set HTTP Request Body
    request.httpBody = data
    
    print("\(request.httpMethod!) \(request.url!)")
    print(request.allHTTPHeaderFields!)
    print(String(data: request.httpBody ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8)!)
    
    
    
    // Perform HTTP Request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            // Check for Error
            if let error = error {
                print("Error took place \(error)")
                return
            }
     
            // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
            if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
                self.openAIResponse = dataString
            }
    }
    task.resume()
    
}`
```

If I print the http request, it seems fine for me as well:

```
 POST https://api.openai.com/v1/completions
 ["Authorization": "Bearer blaaaaa"]
 {
    "temperature" : 0.5,
    "model" : "text-davinci-003",
    "prompt" : "just a test",
    "max_tokens" : 300
 }
```

I tried to use the same payload in my Postman request. It worked fine here. I also tried to use different encodings, but it always throws the same error.

Not sure, what I am doing wrong. Maybe someone can help?

Thank you in advance.

Bets,
Tobi

Comment: Have you tried adding `"Content-Type"` as an header with value `"application/json"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTTP request reveals the problem. You need to add `'Content-Type: application/json'`.

According to [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type/):

> `Content-Type` is an HTTP header that is used to indicate the media type
> of the resource and in the case of responses, it tells the browser
> about what actually content type of the returned content is.